# How to Calculate silhouette coefficient in SPSS for clustered data set?

Tags: clustering, spss

I am having a pre clustered dataset with data and the action cluster identified for it using a custom clustering method. I am looking to calculate silhouette coefficient on this clustered dataset using SPSS to determine the quality of clusters created; any idea how i can do that?

Comment: I have a SPSS macro. May send it to you if you leave your email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get silhouette plots and silhouettte values with the STATS CLUS SIL extension command.
It requires the Python Essentials, which are installed by default with V22, where you can also install this command from the Utilities menu.

On older versions see the SPSS Community website (www.ibm.com/developerworks/spssdevcentral) in the Downloads for SPSS Statistics link.